# wordpress exclude last post

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

SHORTER question

I am using this to get recent posts

```
$args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 20,  'category' => $category );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

but how would I exclude the last post? because for the newest post I want to do something different, for example to include an excerpt. 
And i can call that separately..

I did some search and apparently there is offset, but I'm not sure if it will interfere with pagination when i get to that.

LONGER explanation
(In reality, I could do something like $i = 0 and increment it in foreach loop, and if it is $i==0 i can display an excerpt.. but things are getting somehow complicated since I would like to display them with bootstrap columns, so currently i have this code which puts every post inside col-md-3 but if it already has 4 columns in current row then do that in the next row..

```
    $args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 20,  'category' => $category );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
    $i++;
    setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 


    <?php if($i<4) : ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">  the_title() and other stuff </div>

    <?php else : 
    $i = 0; ?>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3> the_title() and other stuff </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), `get_posts` has an `offset` option.

Just use this like:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 20, 'category' => $category, 'offset' => 1);
$postslist = get_posts($args);
```

This will return the 20 latest posts excluding the very last one.

Comment: That was my question also, will offset interfere with pagination?

Comment: @Marko - This can easily be tested. However, no I would guess not. Instead of doing `0, 20` and `20, 20`, the sql-query is `1, 20` and `21, 20`.